# event don't not be scheduled in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

In AnyLogic, how can I let the event be touched after running the simulation, so each time I don't need to copy the table from Log and paste it to excel. I tried to use the database to store the variables but it seems too complicated and I couldn't work with it!

When I ran model in anylogic, event can't be touched off. It showed that  event don't be scheduled. I try many ways, but it is also that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The image you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with writing to Excel, even though your description says your goal is to "copy table from Log and pate to excel."

Comment: I seriously don't understand the question, but sales.restart() doesn't work unless the even it triggered by the user, not by a condition... In your picture also productionstock size is 0, so why should your event be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about calling event after simulation:
In main, you can call a function on destroy. At the experiment level, you can also call a function after run, iteration, or experiment.